# Eclipse crashing frequently

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Eclipse is crashing within 5 minutes of opening it. Eclipse version I am using is 4.4-luna.
Below is the error log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b1568210c24, pid=6792, tid=0x00002b15822de940
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x815c24]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_loop_late_post(Node*)+0x144
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

Comment: saw the post, not helpful

Comment: Have you tried doing `ulimit -c unlimited` in a terminal and then started eclipse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like it might be the JVM bug discussed in Eclipse bugzilla report [465693](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465693).

A workaround was added in Eclipse 4.5.1

The bug also suggests trying adding one of the following to the `-vmargs` in your `eclipse.ini`:

```
-XX:-UseLoopPredicate
```

or

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/TypeConverter.decodeType
```

Comment: which is apparently https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6675699 java bug which should be resolved in 8u92b31 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/documentation/8u92-revision-builds-relnotes-2994940.html and upcoming versions

Comment: That bug was resolved. This JRE seems to be version 8u92.

Comment: You were correct. I deleted my answer. My bad.

But this bug has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, -XX:-UseLoopPredicate helped me. I got this error today 26.7.2016. I could not edit single word untill eclipse crashed ;-( Before that no such problems.

I notised that my Ubuntu 14.4 had updated java 23.6.2012 to a  1.8.0_101-b13. I tried also older version with eclipse 1.8.0_92-b14 but it did not help. But that option helped me.

There is also never build (102) available in Oracles Java pages, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score -1):

Add below line in your eclipse.ini file and relaunch.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Comment: did that, still it's crashing

Comment: Where you added this line in file?Try to add after -vmargs.

Comment: is there any reason that changing the default browser should fix a crash of the JVM?